# Adding retrospective tags in Git?

Tags: git, github

So unlike some of the SVN migration questions on here, I'm migrating to Git from 'just a bunch of folders on my machine' kind of source control (or lack thereof; I'm the QA engineer, the dev team send me a zip file every now and again, don't laugh too hard.. :).

I've committed the latest code, but I also have a bunch of 'tags' i.e. I made a copy of the project into a separate root folder just after deploying to production.

Now the thing is the contents of these tag folders aren't necessarily in a consistent format (folders inside each tag might be named with various internal version numbers, and they have backups of the binaries but the format of those changed over time etc)

All looks a bit like this (somewhat simplified):

```
DuckProject
  DuckProject 1.2
    R1
    R2
    R3    
  DuckProject 1.3
    R1
    R2
  DuckProject 1.4
    R1
    R2
    R3  <- copied elsewhere as '../GitHub/DuckProject' and uploaded to GitHub

  Tags
    DuckProject 1.2 tag  <- want to upload and mark as a tag
      R3
      R3_BINARY.TAR
    DuckProject 1.3 tag  <- want to upload and mark as a tag
      R2
      archived_binaries
        r2_debugbinary.zip
        r2_releasebinary.zip
```

So basically I want to upload the 1.2 tag and 1.3 tag folders to GitHub, but don't really care about tracking changes between the tag versions, or even relative to HEAD. But I do care about tracking changes from 1.4 R3 onwards, and eventually '1.4 R7' or whatever will need to be tagged, ideally in a way that's reasonably consistent with the 'retrospective' tags.

So (bearing in mind I'm picking all this up as I go along!) what's the best way to do this with Git?

Answer (score 1):

You could create them as commits with no parent and then tag them using `git tag`. This will be consistent with tags on new versions created also using `git tag`.

To create a commit with no parent that has a tag pointing to it, do something like:

1. create temporary branch with no parent

   ```
   git checkout --orphan tmp
   ```
2. commit the files from the archive to the temporary branch (it seems you will have to clean up after the previous branch using `git rm -f` before doing that)
3. tag the commit

   ```
   git tag v1.2
   ```
4. move back to the `master` branch

   ```
   git checkout master
   ```
5. delete the temporary branch

   ```
   git branch -D tmp
   ```